# Hartog's theorem why continuity of $f$ is needed in the first step?

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I was reading Paul Garrett's note about [Hartogs’ Theorem](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/complex/hartogs.pdf) . In the first step to prove separate analyticity implies joint.

We assume $f$ is a separate analytic function on a polydisk $U\subset \Bbb{C}^n$, and $f$ is **continuous on $\bar{U}$** , the proof goes as follows, however I can't see where use the continuity of $f$?

Since separately analytic we can apply Cauchy integral formula on each variable iteratively.

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(2 \pi i)^n} \int_{C_1} \ldots \int_{C_n} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\left(\zeta_1-z_1\right) \ldots\left(\zeta_n-z_n\right)} d \zeta_1 \ldots d \zeta_n$$

Then we have the expansion :$$\frac{1}{\zeta_j-z_j}=\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{z_j^n}{\zeta_j^{n+1}}$$

when $|z_j|<|\zeta_j|$ and the series converge uniformly and absolutely on a compact subset of this disk.

Therefore we can interchange the sum and integral and the result is a jointly analytic function.

I can't figure out why continuous of $f$ is needed in the first set, we only need boundness of $f$ in the above proof?

Answer (score 1):

It is an assumption of Cauchy's theorem for $n=1$, and I presume also for $n\in\Bbb N$ arbitrary, that the function be continuous on the boundary as well as analytic on the interior of the contour (or open set),

Comment: Hello @Martin R , then where do we use continuity?

Comment: @yili My own study of complex analysis was very cursory and I'm not the best person to ask about the rigorous details. However, I am sure that continuity is an assumption (which I recall being used in the proof of Cauchy's theorem). An alternative view; continuity may be assumed (replaceable, perhaps, with just 'integrability) to apply Fubini's theorem for these integrals over the boundary

Comment: It is not assumed to be analytic on $\overline{U}$, so we need to further assume (separate) continuity on $\overline{U}\setminus U$ (i.e. it needs to be separately continuous over each $C_j$) Of course, it is separately continuous on $U$. I suspect that to rigorously handle the iterative use of the Cauchy integrals, joint continuity on $\partial U$ should be used to show the integrals are themselves continuous on the boundary, but I've not checked in detail. If my hunch is right, that explains why more than separate continuity on $\partial U$ is needed.

Comment: However @FShrike , you can take smaller $C_1,....,C_n$ inside $U$? since the result is local?

Comment: As I understand it, the boundary is not relevant because this is a local theorem and you can always make $U$ smaller. And for Cauchy's theorem you only need continuity in each variable, not total continuity.

Comment: @MartinR The author uses $C_j$ to be the boundary circles, and in this way you can keep the same expression for all $z\in U$ (maybe Garret wants this for convenience). Cauchy needs separate continuity, but I'm not sure if separate continuity alone allows you to string together the iterative integrals (treating each inner integral as an analytic+continuous-on-boundary function to be further integrated). But, you're a far better analyst than I. If you find a satisfactory resolution, I'd appreciate a notification

Comment: And I found Joseph Taylor's several complex variables book has a similar result called Osgood's lemma in page 24, which only use boundness on each compact subset don't needs continuity.

Comment: I *assume* that you need it for Fubini's theorem (as @FShrike also said in a comment). Fubini requires the functions to be integrable on the product domain, so “measurable and bounded” may be sufficient.